# Can not run phpstan under docker with memory lack error

Tags: laravel, docker, phpstan

I try to run phpstan(nunomaduro/larastan 2.6.3) under docker (based on php:8.1.6-apache) in laravel 10.8 app and got memory lack error.

I added memory limit in console command, but error anyway :

```
root@3ab9f820c86d:/var/www/PostsTagsCRUDTest_DOCKER_ROOT# ./vendor/bin/phpstan analyse  --memory-limit 1M > phpstan.txt
Warning: Failed to set memory limit to 1048576 bytes (Current memory usage is 41943040 bytes) in phar:///var/www/PostsTagsCRUDTest_DOCKER_ROOT/vendor/phpstan/phpstan/phpstan.phar/src/Command/CommandHelper.php on line 101
Memory limit "1M" cannot be set.
root@3ab9f820c86d:/var/www/PostsTagsCRUDTest_DOCKER_ROOT# ./vendor/bin/phpstan analyse  --memory-limit 0.5M > phpstan.txt
Invalid memory limit format "0.5M".

For more details see free(1).
root@3ab9f820c86d:/var/www/PostsTagsCRUDTest_DOCKER_ROOT# free
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         8057500     6022512      483432      201228     1551556     1532956
Swap:        2104476     1424128      680348
```

In virtualhost.conf of the docker project I got option :

```
php_value  memory_limit  4048M
```

If there is a way to fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `virtualhost.conf` value does not do anything because that's only for your webserver, but you're executing PHPStan from CLI (as you should).

Memory limit "1M" cannot be set because that's a much smaller value than the default (128M).

You can try running PHPStan with the same value you have for your webserver:

```
./vendor/bin/phpstan analyse  --memory-limit 4048M
```

That should work.